# CSV file data Organization( Structured Data)

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have been trying to extract data from this csv file and organize it in a way i can view the data a bit more clearly. The objective is to create 2 dictionaries. One that holds data from the regions listed in the csv. And another another that holds data from countries in the csv. I am having trouble looping thru the data.The csv file starts listing all of the regions first. Not until the'ID' column reaches the number 4 is when the countries began i juts need help organizing that. i have this thus far. But i still need help organizing it based on region and country. 
Link to the csv file is:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1v68_QQX7Tn96l-b0LMO9YZ4ZAn_KWDMUJboa6LEyPr8/edit?usp=sharing

```
import csv

f = open('dph_SYB60_T03_Population Growth, Fertility and Mortality Indicators.csv')

reader = csv.DictReader(f)

data_by_region = {}
data_by_country = {}
answers = []


for line in reader:
  #Collects all the region names
  regions = line['Region/Country/Area'] 
  # Gets All the Years
  years = line['Year']
  # print(regions)



  if regions not in data_by_region:
    data_by_region[regions] = {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would be help:

```
import csv

f = open('dph_SYB60_T03_Population Growth, Fertility and Mortality Indicators.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')

reader = csv.DictReader(f)

data_by_region = {}
data_by_country = {}
answers = []

for line in reader:
    # Collects all the region names
    regions = line['Region/Country/Area']
    # Gets All the Years
    years = line['Year']
    # print(regions)

    if regions not in data_by_region:
        data_by_region[regions] = [line]
    else:
        data_by_region[regions].append(line)

# print data count group by regions.
for region, data_list in data_by_region.items():
    print('{:>30s}: {} rows.'.format(region, len(data_list)))
```

Output:

```
 Total, all countries or areas: 21 rows.
                        Africa: 18 rows.
               Northern Africa: 21 rows.
            Sub-Saharan Africa: 21 rows.
                Eastern Africa: 18 rows.
                 Middle Africa: 18 rows.
               Southern Africa: 18 rows.
                Western Africa: 18 rows.
              Northern America: 18 rows.
...
```

Answer (score 0):

python has a built-in function `groupby` help you group data, but it needs you to sort the list with your group key, so if you want group by `Region/Country/Area`, you need to sort it first. the following snippet should help group your data quickly.

```py
import csv
import itertools

def csv_iter(filepath):
    with open(filepath, mode="r", encoding="utf-8-sig") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        yield from reader

def main():
    filepath = "dph_SYB60_T03_Population Growth, Fertility and Mortality Indicators.csv"
    data_list = sorted(csv_iter(filepath), key=lambda x: x.get("Region/Country/Area", ""))
    for g, v in itertools.groupby(data_list, key=lambda x: x.get("Region/Country/Area", "")):
        print("{}: {}".format(g, len(list(v))))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

output:

```
Afghanistan: 21
Africa: 18
Albania: 21
Algeria: 21
American Samoa: 9
Andorra: 6
Angola: 21
Anguilla: 9
Antigua and Barbuda: 18
Argentina: 21
......
```

But there is a problem related to your understanding of your data, not all region id is below than `4`, for example, the `Northern Africa` has id `15`, so you can not distinct region and country from its ID, you need find all name and build a list of region and country, then you can distinguish whether a line belongs to region or country.